# How to catch an empty query exception with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

**I'm after an elegant and efficient approach.**

I am doing a query to a model that has a chance to return an empty queryset and if that happens I must do a query with other parameters that will work for sure.

It would be really nice if I could put the query inside a simple try except but it doesn't catch like so.

What's holding me back from using .exists() is that it feels like I'm doing the query to the database two times. One to check the existence and the other to really get the object.

Comment: You could do `if len(my_queryset)` with which you can check if it's empty or not, and also evaluate it, but only doing one db hit

Comment: Update question with code sample that way we can better answer.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid double-query you can do:

```
objects = models.MyModel.objects.filter(key=value)

if not objects:
    objects = models.MyModel.objects.filter(another_key=another_value)
```

In this case `bool(objects)` does **not** evaluate query for existance unlike using `exists` or `len()`

Per documentation:

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists() will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Comment: nice! I'm gonna stick to this one. I don't think I can get a better option for now. Good to know about the documentation aswell. I've been using the exists() in big databases in the past. Think I have a chance here to improve performance in some programs. Thanks